# How to select/edit proper folder for unit test creation in Android Studio?

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio

In Android studio, I used to be able to generate a unit test for a class really easily by using the hotkey: `CMD + SHIFT + T`. It would always find the correct folder for placing it (obviously with other unit tests)

but for some reason, after switching to gradle, shifting some tests folders around, Android studio seems really confused and the hotkey tries to create a unit test under the generated folders. and there's no way to select what parent folder i want (from system)

is there a way to modify this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you made changes to where Android Studio expects your sourcesets (done in the build.gradle file), you cannot move where your tests are.  By default studio expects your tests to be in src/androidTest/java/package (make sure you are in at least version .46), once you create this directory you will see the java folder appear as green which is a recognized test folder by studio.  In IntelliJ you were able to change the test sources within the project structure window, but in Android Studio this screen seems to not exist. Now when you use cmd+shift+T it will work correctly